# CharacterStreamReadingMessageSource don't receive from in stream

Tags: java-8, spring-integration

I have [app](https://gist.github.com/wertklop/d921881f9eb949912bb9f291e1214070). When it run from IDE and then execute "echo test > /proc/app_pid/fd/0", method `CommandConsoleHandler#handleMessageInternal` invoking, but if app packed to deb-package, install as service and after start put in terminal command "service app send", above method not invoking. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something not enough. Your app isn't going to work at all: there is need `@EnableIntegration` alongside with the `@Configuration`. Otherwise, please, really share the whole project on GitHub to let us poll it and play locally.

Comment: i'm use spring-boot and spring-batch-integration, it not enough? Other intergation beans working

Comment: Well, you didn't mention Spring Boot... I think that `stdin` is really not going work when it is service. Not sure how to help. Need to dig....